# With Rhino Mocks should BackToRecord() also clear the count of the number of times a method was called?

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

From numerous other questions on SO it is said that in order to reset the count of the number of times a method call was made on a mock object you can call BackToRecord() and then Replay().

However this does not work for me. It will reset the stubbed values but not the method call count.

So extending an example from a related question...

```
public interface IFoo { string GetBar(); }
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestRhino()
    {
        var fi = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IFoo>();
        fi.Stub(x => x.GetBar()).Return("A");
        Assert.AreEqual("A", fi.GetBar());
        fi.AssertWasCalled(x=>x.GetBar(), x=>x.Repeat.Once());

        // Switch to record to clear behaviour and then back to replay
        fi.BackToRecord(BackToRecordOptions.All);
        fi.Replay();

        fi.Stub(x => x.GetBar()).Return("B");
        Assert.AreEqual("B", fi.GetBar());
        fi.AssertWasCalled(x => x.GetBar(), x => x.Repeat.Once());
    }
```

This fails on the last line with 'Expected #1, actual #2'.

Am I missing the point or does it simply not work for the method count? Is there anyway to achieve this without creating a new mock?

For reasons that I won't go into I am not able to set up expectations before making the call to GetBar().

Comment: Whats the use case that this needs to be one test?  This sounds like it may be a bug in Rhino.Mocks, but I don't see why you'd want to do what you're asking.  Why not just make two tests?

Comment: We are writing automated Bdd tests and need to switch out an email component with a mock one and then test whether the send method got called. But we are also using Windsor and I don't want to re-register the components afresh for each test as it slows the test suite down too much.

Comment: So this is more integration testing than unit testing.  If you're using Windsor, I wonder if a Handler Selector would help?  You could set some flag that the selector could use to determine which email component to return (the "real" one or the "mocked" one) when doing a Resolve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it doesn't work that way; it is an unusual use case.

Here is one alternative:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestRhino()
{

    var getBarCount = 0;

    var fi = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IFoo>();
    fi.Stub(x => x.GetBar()).Return("A").WhenCalled(x => getBarCount++);
    Assert.AreEqual("A", fi.GetBar());
    Assert.AreEqual(1, getBarCount);

    // Switch to record to clear behaviour and then back to replay
    fi.BackToRecord(BackToRecordOptions.All);
    fi.Replay();
    getBarCount = 0;

    fi.Stub(x => x.GetBar()).Return("B").WhenCalled(x => getBarCount++);
    Assert.AreEqual("B", fi.GetBar());
    Assert.AreEqual(1, getBarCount);
}
```